# How can I get the correct enum Value from an int c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an int and I want to know the corresponding enum value.

Actually have an enum and I want to return the corresponding value for another enum.

I might just use a large switch but I would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: This easily could have been answered by reading the MSDN article on enumerations.  The default value of an enumeration is an integer as LB points out all you need to do is cast it into an integer.

Comment: @Ramhound I can tell from the article ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.71).aspx ) that I can cast from enum to int, but it's not obvious to me I can go the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
 MyEnum m = (MyEnum)((int)otherEnum);


  var en = (StringSplitOptions)SeekOrigin.Begin;
```

Answer (score 5):

How do the two `enum` types "correspond"? If there is no direct link, then yes, a large `switch` statement will be necessary. Otherwise, if they have the same underlying value, then you can simply cast from one type to the other. If you have an `int`, you can also cast that to the desired `enum` type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases, one where the enums are sharing the values, and one when they are sharing the name. You can cast the values and parse the names as shown here. If neither the names nor the values are the same you of course can't do this.

```
public void Test() {
    var one = FirstEnumWithSameValues.Two;
    var two = (SecondEnumWithSameValues) one;

    var three = FirstEnumWithSameName.Two.ToString();
    var four = (SecondEnumWithSameName) Enum.Parse(typeof(SecondEnumWithSameName), three);
}

public enum FirstEnumWithSameValues
{
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3
}

public enum SecondEnumWithSameValues
{
    Uno = 1,
    Due = 2,
    Trez = 3
}

public enum FirstEnumWithSameName
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3
}

public enum SecondEnumWithSameName
{
    One = 4,
    Two = 5,
    Three = 6
}
```